# how to return the empty value to the output file

Tags: linux, loops, terminal

Update: I have updated my idea with coding in details. It's execute in the linux shell.

```
For I in$(cat list.txt) \\the file contains(1,2,3, ,5,6, ,8,9,10)
do 
var1=$(echo $i) 
if $var1 -eq null
then 
$var1 > output1.txt
else
$var1 = "No Record" \\write a value to the variable
$var1 > output1.txt \\put the value to the same output file above 
Fi
done
```

I am new in linux terminal.

I have 1000 source records (say computer names) to find the dedicate information (say location) using for loop with grep from the database, and save the result to the output file using ">"
However, I found that only 40 records found and cannot match the output with the source records.

`for I in $(cat %filename%)

> do
> grep location > output1.txt
> done`

The script runs successfully, however, I found that some information cannot collect because no return value, so I cannot match those 40 return data to my source records, because I don't know which data belongs to the source record.

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem: can you please add a small set of example data to your question? What part of your script is working and what is not working? Also the title of the question seems not to be related to the question except the keywords "for" and "terminal", maybe you can put your question into one short sentence into the heading and describe the details in the body please?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have amended the description again, thank you.

Comment: Welcome on board, please provide sample input with sample output